# Is there some connection between Band gaps and avoided crossings?

Tags: condensed-matter, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

In abstract sense, are they one and the same phenomenon? We see band gaps when we consider Bloch Waves, etc... in periodic lattice and avoided crossings can happen even if we consider classically coupled harmonic oscillators.

Comment: Not every avoided crossing is a band gap, but every band gap is an avoided crossing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this.

Comment: Try [this other post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/193420/why-are-band-maxima-minima-often-always-at-high-symmetry-points).